# Display Category and subcategory in structure using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I am working in php and mysql, I have a table category, I need to display subcategoies under parent categories. Like

cat1

```
  -> Subcat1

         -> Subcat11

  -> Subcat2

         --> Subcat21

              --> Subcat211
```

cat2

```
  -> Subcat2

         -> Subcat21

              -->Subcat22
  -> Subcat3

         --> Subcat31

              --> Subcat311
```

My Table structure is like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `cat_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'This is primary key of the table',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_cat_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

can you please help me out, how can execute my query.

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
<?php
class RightMenu {
    public $menu;
    public $patch = '';

    public function getMenu($parent = 0) {
        $DB = new DataBase();
        $result = $DB->exec("SELECT * FROM cont_sections WHERE parentid = $parent AND status = 1 ORDER BY name;");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if($row['parentid'] == 0){
                    $this->patch = '';
                }
                $this->patch .= '/' . $row["translit"];
                echo '<li><a href="/section'.$this->patch.'.html">' . $row["name"] . '</a>';
                echo $this->getMenu($row["id"]);
                echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        unset($DB);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a recursive function to display Category & sub-cat

```
getAllSubCats(0);

function getAllSubCats($cat, $depth = NULL)
{
    $this_cat = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("select * from categories where id= '$cat'"));

    $indent = str_repeat("     ", $depth);
    echo $indent . $this_cat->name . "<br />";

    $result = mysql_query("select * from categories where parent_cat_id = '$cat'");

    while($cat = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        getAllSubCats($cat->id, $depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Or use following query If it is one 2 one relation

```
SELECT cat_id, name, (SELECT name FROM categories WHERE cat_id = a.parent_id) parent_name FROM categories a
```

Answer (score 0):

use **SELF JOIN**

```
SELECT p.cat_id, p.name, c.cat_id, c.name
FROM tbl_category p
INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON p.cat_id = c.parent_cat_id
```

Then manipulate the resultant array with PHP to display in tabular form